# using canvas kinetic in html5 to draw many text and edit them

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, kineticjs

When I click the text on a card, I want to be able to edit the text like this website:

http://www.vistaprint.com/vp/ns/studio3.aspx?pf_id=064&combo_id=120585&free_studio_gallery=true&referer=http%3a%2f%2fwww.vistaprint.com%2fvp%2fns%2fdefault.aspx%3fdr%3d1%26rd%3d1%26GNF%3d0%26GP%3d5%252f19%252f2012%2b12%253a36%253a37%2bAM%26GPS%3d2448654652%26GNF%3d1%26GPLSID%3d&rd=1

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var Total_layers = 0;

    var Text = {};
    /*set up stage for drawing image*/
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: "container",
        width: 600,
        height: 400
    });
    // var Layer = {};
    /*create a layer object for placing text image over it and place it over the stage*/
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    //Layer[Total_layers]
    /*Text Property*/
    var New_Text = "Company Name";
    var Text_Font = "Arial";
    var Text_Color = "Black";

    var Text_Size = "30";
    var Text_Pos_X = 200;
    var Text_Pos_y = 100;
    var Selected_Text = new Kinetic.Text({});
    var current_layer = 0;
    // var text_selected = 1;

    /*Add event for them*/
    //var formElement = document.getElementById("New Text");

    // formElement.addEventListener('change', Text_Changed, false);

    var formElement = document.getElementById("selectFontSize");
    formElement.addEventListener('change', Text_Size_Changed, false);
    /*This Function will be Executed when the Size of the Text in consideration is changed*/
    function Text_Size_Changed(e) {
        var target = e.target;
        Text_Size = target.value;
        Text_Pos_X = 200; //Text[Total_layers].x;
        Text_Pos_Y = 100; //Text[Total_layers].y;
        //DeleteLayer(Total_layers);
        layer.remove(Selected_Text);
        Draw_text(Total_layers);
    }

    /*Function to swap the Kinetic Text object and get the selected Text object to The Top*/
    function swap_layers(Selected_text) {

        var temp = new Kinetic.Text({});

        for (var i = 1; i <= Total_layers; i++) {

            if (Text[i] == Selected_text) {

                temp = Text[i];
                Text[i] = Text[Total_layers];
                Text[Total_layers] = temp;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /*Add different Events to the Text objects once They are instantiated*/

    function add_events(dest_Text) {

        dest_Text.on("mouseover", function () {
            document.body.style.cursor = "pointer";
        });
        dest_Text.on("mouseout", function () {
            document.body.style.cursor = "default";
        });
        dest_Text.on("click", function () {

            $("#selectFontSize").change(function () {
                dest_Text.setFontSize($("#selectFontSize").val());
                layer.draw(); // vì gọi layer.draw nên tất cả text trong layer đó đều dc vẽ lại 
            });
            $("#selectFontFamily").change(function () {
                swap_layers(dest_Text);
                //dest_Text.setFontFamily($("#selectFontFamily").val());

                //layer.draw();
            });

        });

    }

    /*Draw the Text over the layer depening upon the Text_object_Number*/
    function Draw_text(Text_object_Number) {

        /*Set the Properties of the Topmost object that is been modified and which will be added to the layer*/
        Text[Text_object_Number] = new Kinetic.Text({

            x: Text_Pos_X,
            y: Text_Pos_Y,
            text: New_Text,
            fontSize: Text_Size,
            fontFamily: Text_Font,
            textFill: Text_Color,
            align: "center",
            verticalAlign: "middle",
            draggable: "true"

        });

        /*Adds all the Text objects onto the layer and adds the events to every Text object */
        //for (var i = 1; i <= Text_object_Number; i++) {
        layer.add(Text[Text_object_Number]);
        add_events(Text[Text_object_Number]);
        //}
        stage.add(layer);
    }
    $("#add_text").click(function () {
        Total_layers++;
        Text[Total_layers] = new Kinetic.Text({
            x: Text_Pos_X,
            y: Text_Pos_y,
            text: New_Text,
            fontSize: 30,
            fontFamily: Text_Font,
            textFill: Text_Color,
            align: "center",
            verticalAlign: "middle",
            draggable: "true"
        });
        add_events(Text[Total_layers]);
        layer.add(Text[Total_layers]);
        stage.add(layer);
    });

    /*Adding an image to the present Context*/
    var imageObj = new Image();
    //alert("abc");
    imageObj.onload = function () {
        var T_shirt = new Kinetic.Image({
            x: 60,
            y: 0,
            image: imageObj,
            width: 550,
            height: 400,
            name: "image"
        });

        layer.add(T_shirt);
        stage.add(layer);
    }
    imageObj.src = "../../Content/Image/imagepreview1.jpg";
});
```

I have tried many ways, but I still can't resolve this problem.

How can I do this by using canvas kineticjs in html5?

Comment: put some code in a jsfiddle and I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

The very best solution imho is to use a simple JavaScript prompt:

```
myText.on('click', function(evt) {
    this.setText(prompt('New Text:'));
    layer.draw(); //redraw the layer containing the textfield
});
```

See my answer in this thread: [editable Text option in kinetic js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13271436/editable-text-option-in-kinetic-js/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit the text directly on the canvas, but what you can do is change it with events. So what you need is an input form that is created next to the canvas, and you can read from the form using javascript.

```
 <input type=text id=changeText/>
```

this way when you click on some text a new input tag will appear and you can type in it and the text inside of the canvas will change as you type.

```
 mytext.on('click', function(){ ... create new input element at the side ... });
 //add some jQuery
 $('#changeText').onchange( mytext.setText($('$changeText').val()));
```