# editable Text option in kinetic js

Tags: javascript, text, kineticjs

I want to add `Textbox` or editable element to give the user the option to edit the text.

This is my current code:

```
var text = new Kinetic.Text({
        text: "Sample Text", ---> i want to edit this text 
        x: 50,
        y: 10,
        fill: "transparent",
        fontSize: 10,
        fontFamily: "Helvetica Neue",
        textFill: "#000",
        align: "center",
        verticalAlign: "middle",
        name:'TEXT'
    });
```

Answer (score 11):

At the moment there does not seem to be any way to create editable text with Kinetic JS (see several threads about this at stackoverflow), some people suggest using an input field next to the canvas to edit the text, but my solution would be the following:

- create a text with your code
- on text click [text.on("click", function...], create an input field right at your mouse cursor

Well, that´s the plan. Maybe it´s easier to use a "save" button text to the input field, so you know exactly when to close it and when to store the input field data to the Kinetic text. you would also need a "close" function if you don´t want to edit it.

A very easy solution would also be a simple JavaScript prompt:

`var xy = prompt("gimme your text");`

So, something like this would be the best Solution imho:

```
myText.on('click', function(evt) {
    this.setText(prompt('New Text:'));
    layer.draw(); //redraw the layer containing the textfield
});
```

Comment: I am using this approach for text editing. The problem is scaling of the input field along with kinetic stage. When I am using a small window and scaled the stage to fit that window, the input field I am getting is still big sized. Can you suggest workaround for that?

Comment: i don´t think you can change the appearance of the js prompt, it´s a browser thing. another solution would be to overlay a html input field. that one you could scale.

Comment: ...it would be a lot more work though...the prompt solution is very easy.

Comment: I am trying to simulate text feature from ms paint on kineticJS. I am using input field. Will try out with scale. Thanks.

Comment: you can just use css to scale the input field then

Answer (score 2):

I've made an attempt for an actual KinetiJS plugin with editable text functionality.

I know it's reinventing the wheel, when you can just hover a textarea, but why not have it only in canvas too.

Check the plugin out at: https://github.com/nktsitas/kineticjs-editable-text

Answer (score 1):

I did this some days back on my project. Hare are the code snippets. Basically we first draw the rectangle and then put a text area inside it and finally convert it into kinetic.text node.

```
             drawText: function ( color )
            {
                var layer1=this.model.stage.getLayers()[0];
                var $this=this;
                console.log('drawText: color: ' + color);

                if($this.rectangleDrawn==true)
                {

                    var down = false, oPoint;
                    layer1.off("mousedown touchstart mousemove touchmove mouseup touchend");
                    if(group!=undefined && group!='')
                    {
                        $this.hideAnchors(group);
                    }
                    console.log("textX: "+textX);
                    //after rectangle is drawn we now have to add the editablesection
                    $('<textarea id="text" type="text"  width='+textWidth +'px height='+textHeight+'px style="font-size: 30px;font-family:Calibri;height:'+textHeight+'px;width:'+textWidth+'px;position:absolute'+';left:'+textX+'px'+';top:'+textY+'px'+';z-index:5'+';background-color:#ffcc00;"></textarea>')

                    .insertBefore('.kineticjs-content');
                    $('#text').on('blur',function()
                    {
                        console.log("textchange");
                        text = new Kinetic.Text( {
                            x: textX,
                            y: textY,
                            stroke: color,
                            strokeWidth: 1,
                            fontSize: 30,
                            fontFamily: 'Calibri',
                            clearBeforeDraw: false,
                            name: 'image'+layer1.getName(),
                            draggable: true,
                            height: textHeight,
                            width: textWidth,
                            text: $('#text').val()
                        } );
                        text.on( 'mouseleave dbltap', function ()
                        {
                            text=this;
                        } );
                        $('#text').remove();

                        layer1.add( text );
                        layer1.draw(); 
                    })
                    },drawRectangle: function ( opacity, colorFill,stroke,textColor ){rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
                    x: mousePos.x,
                    y: mousePos.y,
                    width: 0,
                    height: 0,
                    stroke: stroke,
                    strokeWidth: 4,
                    opacity: opacity,
                    clearBeforeDraw: false,
                    name: 'image'+layer1.getName()
                });
                layer1.on( "mouseup touchend", function ( e )
                {
                console.log("rectangle: mouseup");
                console.log("width: "+rect.getWidth(  ));
                rect.setOpacity(opacity);
                rect.setFill(colorFill);
                layer1.draw();
                    down = false;
                    console.log("textColor: "+textColor)
                    if(textColor!=undefined)
                    {
                        textWidth=rect.getWidth(  );
                        textHeight=rect.getHeight(  );
                        textX = rect.getAbsolutePosition().x;
                        textY=rect.getAbsolutePosition().y;
                        $this.rectangleDrawn=true;
                        $this.drawText(textColor);
                        console.log("textdrawn ");
                        $this.group.remove();
                    }

        },
```