# text input box with kineticjs

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I want to create something like [this](http://www.periodontalchart-online.com/uk/) with kineticjs. But I can't find the way to have text input and buttons using KineticJs like with flash? Is it possible?

Comment: [Text input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13271436/editable-text-option-in-kinetic-js); [Button](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/NxTW7/4/)

Comment: Not very easy to implement. The Text Input I mean. I want to be able to retrieve text from it too.

Comment: The best way to insert a text field is through a modal in HTML. Looks nice and easy to make.

Comment: Any tutorilas on this? You mean the javascript promt function? Modal Window?

Comment: What I meant is just a simple `<div>` overlay along with a `textarea` or an `input` something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I think creating DOM `<input>` and place it on top of stage is only one good way to use input.

```
<div id="con"></div>
<input type='text' id='input'>
```

css:

```
#input {
  position : absolute;
  top : 30px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/reqile/1/edit